# how do I copy one table to another in different field AND add date( table2 dont have datetime)

Tags: php, mysqli

here is the scenario.
 table1 have fieldname of `teacher`, `score` and `archive_time` (I didnt include date in table2), 
table2 have fieldname of `lname`, `cof_score`
how do I insert date in table2?

```
$backup = "INSERT INTO table1(teacher, score,archive_time) SELECT lname, AVG(cof_score) FROM table2 GROUP BY lname";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the current date you can use the [Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

So depending on the format of your archive time column in table 2, your script would look like

```
$backup = "INSERT INTO table1(teacher, score,archive_time) 
  SELECT lname, AVG(cof_score), date("Y-m-d H:i:s") 
  FROM table2 GROUP BY lname";
```

Comment: my format in date is date, I tried date('Y-m-d') but still not working